# The method encode(byte[], int) is undefined for the type Base64. Post API call

Tags: java, base64

How can i resolve error in this line in the code

```
encodedBytes = Base64.encode(authorization.getBytes(), 0);  it is saying undefined method.
```

Below is the complete code.

```
package postapicall;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Base64;

public class PostApi1 {
    
     public static void main(String []args)
     {
         
    
    try
    {
        String authorization = "";
        String url= "https://idcs-82972921e42641b1bf08128c3d93a19c.identity.c9dev2.oc9qadev.com/oauth2/v1/token";
        String username = "idcs-oda-9417f93560b94eb8a2e2a4c9aac9a3ff-t0_APPID";
        String password = "244ae8e2-6f71-4af2-b5cc-xxxxx";
        URL address = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection hc = (HttpURLConnection) address.openConnection();

        hc.setDoOutput(true);
        hc.setDoInput(true);
        hc.setUseCaches(false);

        if (username != null && password != null) {
            authorization = username + ":" + password;
        }

        if (authorization != null) {
            byte[] encodedBytes;
            encodedBytes = Base64.encode(authorization.getBytes(), 0);
            authorization = "Basic " + encodedBytes;
            hc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization);
        }

   }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    
}

}
```

Basic requirement is I have to receive `bearer token` by calling above endpoint with POST method. I am sending username and password and in return I want token from the endpoint.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the complete error message.

Comment: Are those real credentials (user name and pw)? You just published them to anyone on the internet.

Comment: Credentials are changed. they are not real.

Comment: I have added error in subject line

Comment: did you mean `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is stating exactly, what the problem is:

```
The method encode(byte[], int) is undefined for the type Base64
```

It is telling you that there is no method with the signature `encode(byte[], int)` on the Base64-Class.

Let's have a look at the [Base64 javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) (assuming you are using java 8).
I can't spot any method with the name "encode" at all, so
java seems to be right with it's error message.

BUT, there are some static method to get actual the encoders like this:

```
Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
```

This encoder offers the actual encoding methods that you need:

```
String encoded = encoder.encodeToString(contentBytes);
```

So, to fix that error it should be sufficient to replace

```
// original source (indentation changed)
if (authorization != null) {
    byte[] encodedBytes;
    encodedBytes = Base64.encode(authorization.getBytes(), 0);
    authorization = "Basic " + encodedBytes;
    hc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization);
}
```

with

```
// Fixed usage of Base64
if (authorization != null) {
    authorization = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authorization.getBytes());
    hc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization);
}
```